# What are the differences between python schedule module and advanced python scheduler module? When to use apscheduler over schedule?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler

I want to schedule my python scripts to run once every Monday on Ubuntu server having 1 GB of RAM, and I am using windows to test my scripts. Which module would work best on both platforms and also in terms of RAM consumption? What are the pros and cons of one over another?

Comment: Normally, on a Linux system, you would use a ` cron ` job to schedule a script to run. This is an operating system "service".  And in Windows you use use a scheduled task. Neither python schedule nor advanced python scheduler will be started automatically by the operating system.

Comment: It makes sense! Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell the difference between both packages python schedule and advanced scheduler python? Also what are the drawbacks if I use python schedulers over operating system schedulers?